# Scraping a page with awkwardly formatted JSON in python

Tags: python, html, json, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping a webpage for data and it has a format like:

```
<!-- Web header up here -->
[{"foo": "Bar", "foo2": "Bar2"},
 {"foo3": ["hello", "world"], "foo4": "Bar4"},
...
]
<!-- Web footer here -->
```

The issue is that the JSON appears on the page with other content, and the page source has the JSON list inside quotes, inside a 'pre' tag with other html tags within the JSON like so:

```
<pre>" [{ "foo": "Bar", <p>"foo2": "Bar2"</p>}, ... ] "</pre>
```

Is there any way to get around this abysmal formatting and get a list of JSON objects given a String-of-a-list-of-JSON-Objects, preferably getting rid of the embedded tags in the process?

**EDIT:** I've now installed and began to learn BeautifulSoup4 as recommended by Mauricio, but I'm still coming up slightly short. Using the .pre operator on the 'soup' gives me

`<pre> [{ ... (Good formatted JSON but inside tags still) ...}]</pre>`

**HTML:** (the `<pre>` code just has some headers above and below it.)

```
<pre>
[{
  "title": “blah”,
  "refs": [“a”, “a”],
  "description": [“a”,
  “a”,
  "a”],
  “a”: [
    {“a”: “a"}]
},
{
  "title": “a”,
  "refs": [“a”, “a”],
  "description": [“a”,
  “a”,
  “a”],
  “a”: [
    {“a”: “a”}]
}]
</pre>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the [`.text`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-text-argument) and [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) quotes and spaces.

Then, you can use [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads) to load the json string:

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = """
<div>
    <pre>" [{ "foo": "Bar", <p>"foo2": "Bar2"</p>}] "</pre>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

json_data = soup.pre.text.strip('" ')
print json.loads(json_data)
```

Prints:

```
[{u'foo': u'Bar', u'foo2': u'Bar2'}]
```

---

There is a another problem - the quotes inside the `pre` are not normal and you should replace them:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = u"""
<div>
    <pre>
[{
  "title": “blah”,
  "refs": [“a”, “a”],
  "description": [“a”,
  “a”,
  "a”],
  “a”: [
    {“a”: “a"}]
},
{
  "title": “a”,
  "refs": [“a”, “a”],
  "description": [“a”,
  “a”,
  “a”],
  “a”: [
    {“a”: “a”}]
}]
</pre>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

json_data = soup.pre.text.encode('utf-8').strip('" ').replace('“', '"').replace('”', '"')
print json.loads(json_data)
```

Prints:

```
[{u'a': [{u'a': u'a'}], u'refs': [u'a', u'a'], u'description': [u'a', u'a', u'a'], u'title': u'blah'}, 
 {u'a': [{u'a': u'a'}], u'refs': [u'a', u'a'], u'description': [u'a', u'a', u'a'], u'title': u'a'}]
```

Comment: For some reason json.loads can't decode anything. Does your method still work if you put another object in your brackets like so: `<pre>" [{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"}] "</pre>`?

Comment: @mlinsenbard please show the complete html, so I can reproduce the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Added it to the question.

Comment: Amazing! Worked like a charm. Thank you a ton. I didn't see that those open/closing quotes existed and were messing everything up. I'd +1 if I could (and will when I can!)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use BeautifulSoup to parse the webpage.

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Docs:

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Then you can do something like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen

html_doc = urlopen("http://www.google.com/").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
print soup.p.text
```

It will extract the text from every tag below P including P itself.

Comment: Thanks! This is getting me close to what I want. Is there a way to omit the tags when getting the data so that I get `[{ ... }]` instead of `<pre>[{ ... }]</pre>` ? The soup.pre.text is giving me a jumbled mess of HTML while just soup.pre is giving me the contents of the page as they appear, but with those tags appended.

Comment: soup.pre.text to me returns only the text, but, if it still have tags, you could do:
BeautifulSoup(soup.pre.text).text